# traversal on tree in Haskell with print

Tags: haskell, tree

I have following toy haskell code for binary search tree. The function preorderV is to traverse the tree with a function applying to every element. It works fine for normal function. However if I apply function "print", I got compiling error. How could I make function related to IO work with preorderV?

Thanks

Code:

```
data BSTree a = EmptyTree | Node a (BSTree a) (BSTree a) deriving (Show)
data Mode = IN | POST | PRE

singleNode :: a -> BSTree a
singleNode x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree

bstInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> BSTree a -> BSTree a
bstInsert x EmptyTree = singleNode x
bstInsert x (Node a left right)
          | x == a = Node a left right
          | x < a  = Node a (bstInsert x left) right
          | x > a  = Node a left (bstInsert x right)

buildTree :: String -> BSTree String
buildTree = foldr bstInsert EmptyTree . words    

preorderV :: (a->b) -> BSTree a -> BSTree b
preorderV f EmptyTree = EmptyTree
preorderV f (Node x left right) = Node (f x) (preorderV f left) (preorderV f right)
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘BSTree’ with ‘IO’
Expected type: IO (IO ())
  Actual type: BSTree (IO ())
In a stmt of a 'do' block: preorderV print $ buildTree content
```

Comment: Could you post the code that contains the `print`? I'm curious why it is expecting type `IO (IO ())` instead of `IO ()` (it would give an error either way, but I wouldn't expect to see `IO (IO ())` here). I suspect that is another, probably separate, problem with the code.

Comment: Print is prelude's function

Comment: I know, I mean you don't have the code surrounding this line of code in your post: `preorderV print $ buildTree content`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `preorderV print $ buildTree content` is `BSTree (IO ())`, that is, you are creating a binary tree of IO computations - you don't have an IO computation itself.

To do what I think you want to do you need to create a monadic version of `preorderV` which has the following type:

```
preorderVM :: (a -> IO ()) -> BSTree a -> IO ()
preorderVM f EmptyTree = ... -- what do you want to do here?
preorderVM f (Node x left right) = do
    f x 
    preorderVM f left
    preorderVM f right
```

Comment: As a note, that type can be generalized to work with any `Applicative`, not just `IO`.

Comment: `preorderVM` is essentially `Data.Traversable.traverse` or `Data.Traversable.mapM`, and GHC can derive `Traversable`, so you don't even have to write this yourself.

Comment: @user2407038 - True, and that's useful to know. OTOH I think it is helpful for beginners to see exactly what is going on before introducing the generalization. Also, this approach shows you how to write `postorderVM` and `inorderVM`.

Answer (score 1):

your code works so far but you got a `BSTree (IO ())` back and as you use this inside a `do` Block (`main` most likely) you get the error.

what you now can do is *fold* over the tree to get the actions back, then you can use `sequence` or something similar to *use* each of those actions one after the other:

```
foldT :: (a -> s -> s) -> s -> BSTree a -> s
foldT _ s EmptyTree = s
foldT f s (Node a left right) =
  let s' = foldT f s left
      s'' = f a s'
  in foldT f s'' right

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let doPrint = preorderV print $ buildTree "C A B D E"
      folded = foldT (:) [] doPrint
  sequence_ . reverse $ folded
```

This will print

```
λ> :main
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
"E"
```

**BTW**: Your `preorderV` is usually called `map` ;)